# Why does my iframe's contentEditable get reset?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, contenteditable

I have a web page with an empty iframe in it, to which I want to assign a source with javascript and make its contents editable.
The problem is that - while I can see that the contents of the frame become editable for a brief moment (the browser starts underlining  words that don't pass spellcheck) - something resets that state and I'm left with an iframe, which has the right content, but the frame's contentWindow.document.body.contentEditable has been reset to the default 'inherit'.

Setting the contentEditable property in console works. So does creating a wait function that changes the contentEditable property after 1000ms. The solution I settled on was making an XMLHttpRequest for the URL I wanted the iframe to contain, assigning the response to a an intermediate html element, changing the contentEditable property of that element's body, then assigning its InnerHTML to the iframe's srcdoc.

So, I have workarounds, but I'd like to understand, what's getting in the way of my initial, simpler approach.

Complete html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function setedit(){
    var editableFrame = document.getElementById("editableFrame");
    editableFrame.src = '/b.html'
    editableFrame.contentWindow.document.body.contentEditable = true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setedit()">
<iframe id="editableFrame"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

b.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Lorem ipsum yadda yadda</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** While the accepted solution with arrow functions works, now I don't understand why it didn't when I wrote it like

```
function setsrc(){
        var theFrame = document.getElementById('the_frame');
        theFrame.src = '/b.html';
        theFrame.onload = setedit();
}
function setedit(){
        var theFrame = document.getElementById('the_frame');
        theFrame.contentWindow.document.body.contentEditable='true';
}
```

**Edit 2:**
Ok, I get it now.

```
theFrame.onload = setedit();
```

Evaluates 'setedit()' there and then, before the iframe's loaded and assigns its return value to the 'onload' property, which is not a valid function.

It also doesn't work if you write

```
theFrame.onload = "setedit()";
```

Presumably because it tries to assign the literal string value to the property, which is not a valid function either.

The frustrating thing and the reason I couldn't figure it out for so log is that neither of those approaches results in an error being logged to the console and neither of them is inconsistent with the way assigning onload handlers looks when you assign them inside the tag i.e.

```
<iframe id="the_frame" onload=setedit()></iframe>
<iframe id="the_frame" onload="setedit()"></iframe>
```

Both assign the 'setedit()' function as the handler of the onload event, except - when defined this way - they end up being called both before and after the parent window onload and fail to change the contentEditable property on the second time around as well for some reason.
You have to construct the function inside the onload of the window either like Kaiido did with arrow functions or in ES5 like so:

```
onload = function(){
    var myFrame = document.getElementById('the_frame');
    myFrame.srcdoc = "<html><body><p>This should be editable</p></body></html>";
    myFrame.onload = function(){
        myFrame.contentDocument.body.contentEditable=true;
    };
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. We can't tell why it resets based on the code you've provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because loading an iframe (just like any resource btw) is an asynchronous task.
So the `editableFrame.contentWindow` you do access (and its `document.body`) is not the same as the one it will be once the document will have loaded.

At the time you call it, it is the one of an empty document; this can be checked by logging the `textContent` of this document for instance.

I have to outsource the [live example to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwxrpdf8/) because null-origined StackSnippets frames don't allow accessing inner-frames content.

```js
window.onload = e => {
  the_frame.src = URL.createObjectURL(
    new Blob([`<html><body>An other doc</body></html>`])
  );
  console.log(
    the_frame.contentWindow.document.documentElement.textContent
  ); // ""

  // while in the iframe's onload event
  the_frame.onload = e =>
    console.log(
      the_frame.contentWindow.document.documentElement.textContent
    ); // "An other doc"
};
```

```html
<iframe id="the_frame"></iframe>
```

So as you might have understood, the solution is to wait for the iframe's onload event to fire after you did change its `src`.

https://jsfiddle.net/zwxrpdf8/1/